# Weak head normal form and order of evaluation

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow, lazy-evaluation, strictness, weak-head-normal-form

I've read lots on weak head normal form and seq. But I'm still have trouble imagining the logic behind Haskell's order of evaluation

A common example demonstrating when and how to use  but I still don't understand how the common example

```
foldl (+) 0 [1..5000000]
```

can result in a stack overflow. While another fold definition using `seq` doesn't

```
foldl' _ a [] = a
foldl' f a (x:xs) = let a' = f a x in a' `seq` foldl' f a' xs
foldl' (+) 0 [0..5000000]
```

From explanations of seq that I've read, authors are very careful to make the following clear:

- The first argument of `seq` is not guaranteed to be evaluated before the second argument
- The first argument of `seq` will only be evaluated to weak head normal form
- The evaluation of the first argument of `seq` will only happen when the second is evaluated to WHNF

So, if the above is correct (is it?) then why does `foldl'` not overflow like `foldl`?

When we reduce one step, shouldn't it looks like this, right?

```
foldl' (+) 0 (1:xs) = let a' = (+) 0 1 in a' `seq` foldl' (+) a' xs
```

In the above, the second argument of `seq` is not in WHNF since there is a function application which needs to be done. Are we guaranteed to evaluate the first argument of `seq` here before we reach the WHNF of the second argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- > The first argument of `seq` is not guaranteed to be evaluated before the second argument

  Not *guaranteed*, but the compiler will try and usually do it if it prevents thunk buildup. The scenario where this doesn't work so well is parallelism, hence the need for [`pseq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/GHC-Conc-Sync.html#v%3apseq) – but for `foldl'` that's not relevant.
- > The first argument of `seq` will only be evaluated to weak head normal form

  Yeah, but for built-in number types WHNF = NF.
- > The evaluation of the first argument of `seq` will only happen when the second is evaluated to WHNF

  Indeed, and that often causes confusion. But `` in a' `seq` foldl' f a' xs `` means, if you request any result at all it'll trigger the `seq`.

  > When we reduce one step, shouldn't it looks like this, right? ... the second argument of `seq` **is not in WHNF**

  Precisely that's what forces the `seq`, because to evaluate the result of `foldl' (+) 0 (1:xs)` you need `foldl' (+) a' xs` to be WHNF, and `seq` ensures this won't happen before `a'` is WHNF.